# Spark sql partition pruning for hive partitioned table

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

When I run some query spark seems not predicate push down to specific hive table's partition.

Setting "spark.sql.orc.filterPushdown" to "true" didn't help.
Spark version is 1.6 and hive version is 1.2. and hive table is partioned by date with ORC format.

```
val sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf())
var hql = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
hql.setConf("spark.sql.orc.filterPushdown", "true")
hql.sql("""
    SELECT i.*, 
        from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('20170220','yyyyMMdd'),"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ") bounce_date
        FROM 
          (SELECT country,
                 device_id,
                 os_name,
                 app_ver
          FROM jpl_band_orc
          WHERE yyyymmdd='20170220'
                  AND scene_id='app_intro'
                  AND action_id='scene_enter'
                  AND classifier='app_intro'
          GROUP BY  country, device_id, os_name, app_ver ) i
        LEFT JOIN 
          (SELECT device_id
          FROM jpl_band_orc
          WHERE yyyymmdd='20170220'
                  AND scene_id='band_list'
                  AND action_id='scene_enter') s
              ON i.device_id = s.device_id
        WHERE s.device_id is null
""")
```

this is show create table

```
1 CREATE TABLE `jpl_band_orc`(
2     ... many fields ...
3     )
39  PARTITIONED BY ( 
40    `yyyymmdd` string)
41  CLUSTERED BY ( 
42    ac_hash) 
43  SORTED BY ( 
44    ac_hash ASC) 
45  INTO 256 BUCKETS
46  ROW FORMAT SERDE 
47    'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde' 
48  STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
49    'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat' 
50  OUTPUTFORMAT 
51    'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat'
52  LOCATION
53    'BLAH~BLAH~/jpl_band_orc'
54  TBLPROPERTIES (
55    'orc.bloom.filter.columns'='ac_hash,action_id,classifier', 
56    'orc.bloom.filter.fpp'='0.05', 
57    'orc.compress'='SNAPPY', 
58    'orc.row.index.stride'='30000', 
59    'orc.stripe.size'='268435456', 
60    'transient_lastDdlTime'='1464922691')
```

Spark job output

```
17/02/22 17:05:32 INFO HadoopFsRelation: Listing leaf files and directories in parallel under:
hdfs://banda/apps/hive/warehouse/jpl_band_orc/yyyymmdd=20160604, hdfs://banda/apps/hive/warehouse/jpl_band_orc/yyyymmdd=20160608, 
...
hdfs://banda/apps/hive/warehouse/jpl_band_orc/yyyymmdd=20160620, hdfs://banda/apps/hive/warehouse/jpl_band_orc/yyyymmdd=20160621,
```

Finally ended with OOM

```
Exception in thread "qtp1779914089-88" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at java.util.HashMap$KeySet.iterator(HashMap.java:912)
    at java.util.HashSet.iterator(HashSet.java:172)
    at sun.nio.ch.Util$2.iterator(Util.java:243)
    at org.spark-project.jetty.io.nio.SelectorManager$SelectSet.doSelect(SelectorManager.java:600)
    at org.spark-project.jetty.io.nio.SelectorManager$1.run(SelectorManager.java:290)
    at org.spark-project.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.spark-project.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:3664)
    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:207)
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1969)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.substring(URI.java:2869)
```

It seems read all partitions then OOM occured.
How can I check whether It partition pruned or not exactly.

Comment: Did you check https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Advanced-Analytics-Apache-Spark/sparkSQL-not-pruning-directiories/td-p/46774 and also https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/39646/spark-sql-on-hive-tables.html ?